# How does GR reconcile its model of a smooth manifold against the limitations of the planck length?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, relativity, conventions, models

To paraphrase the classic text, *Gravitation* by Misner, Thorne, and Wheeler, it is said that we are to accept the model of a continuous spacetime manifold, despite the calculated "violent fluctuations in the geometry at distances on the order of the Planck length", due to the observed behavior of particles at more macroscopic scales.

Is there a deeper justification for this methodology than simple convenience? Are we making an assumption about spacetime (e.g. that it's smooth) or are we simply using such a model for the sake of calculations? If the answer is the latter, how do we reconcile the seemingly continuous nature of spacetime despite the seemingly discontinuous behavior at the Planck scale?

[image]

Comment: GR is a *classical*, not a quantum theory: it doesn't have to account for QM any more than Newtonian mechanics does.  And yes, that means GR is not a complete theory in some limits, in just the same way that Newtonian mechanics is not: that's why people have spent a hundred years trying to work out a quantum gravity theory.